# Laravel4 - Saving a model with multiple relationships/foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've tried to understand a process of saving a model with multiple relationships but I still can't figure out how to do it "kosher" way.

To begin with - I have an Event model that belongs to a category (Eventcat) and a Location:

```
// Event.php

class Event extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'events';

public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Location');
}

public function eventcat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Eventcat');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

}

// Location.php

class Location extends Eloquent
{

protected $table = 'locations';

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Event');
}

}

// Eventcat.php

class Eventcat extends Eloquent
{
protected $table = 'eventcats';

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Event');
}
}
```

I've seeded the database with a few categories and locations and now I trying to get events saving work. I thought that the `$event->eventcat()->associate( $eventcat )` would work but I got a `Call to undefined method eventcat()` error.

```
public function postCreateEvent() {

    $event = new Event();

    $eventcat = Eventcat::find( Input::get('event-create-eventcat[]') );
    $location = Location::find( Input::get('event-create-location[]') );

    $event->title = Input::get('event-create-title');
    $event->description = Input::get('event-create-description');
    $event->price = Input::get('event-create-price');
    $event->start_date = Input::get('event-create-start_date');
    $event->end_date = Input::get('event-create-end_date');

    $event->eventcat()->associate( $eventcat );
    $event->location()->associate( $location );

    $event->save();

}
```

I've read the documentation, API and a few threads here but I still can't figure out the best way to deal with this.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually bet that you have a conflict in your class name.  Laravel contains an `Event` class and I wonder if that isn't what's being called in your code.  As a quick test, you could rename your class `FooEvent` and see if it works.

The best solution is probably namespacing your model (see http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-methods-staying-organized for a quick intro) so that your model can still be called Event without conflicting with the builtin class.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I've actually thought of the same answer, came back here to share and saw yours :) Thanks very much!